# What is the exact limit on the number of collections in a MongoDB database based on the WiredTiger(MongoDB 4.0) engine as of today(May 2019)?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I'm trying to put a forum-like structure in a MongoDB 4.0 database, which consists of multiple threads under a same "topic", each thread consists of a bunch of posts. So usually there are no limits on the numbers of the threads and posts. And I want to try fully utilizing the benefits of NoSQL features, grabbing a list of posts under any speicified thread at one time without having to scan and look up for the identical "thread_id" and "post_id" in a RDBMS table in the traditional way, so in my mind I want to put all the threads as collections in a database, as the thread_id as the code-generated collection names, and put all the posts of a thread as normal documents under that collection, so the way to access a post may look like:

```
forum_db【database name】.thread_id【collection name】.post_id【document ID】
```

But my concern is, despite of the obscure phrase saying at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#data,

```
 Number of Collections in a Database
```

`Changed in version 3.0.

For the MMAPv1 storage engine, the maximum number of collections in a database is a function of the size of the namespace file and the number of indexes of collections in the database.

The WiredTiger storage engine is not subject to this limitation.</pre>`

Is it safe to do it in this way in terms of performance and scalability? Can we safely take it that there is no limit on the number of collections in a WiredTiger database (MongoDB 4.0+) today as there is pratically no limit on the number of documents in a collection? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with having to scan for thread_id?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate how many collections one can store in a MongoDB database, you need to figure out the number of indexes in each collection.

WiredTiger engine keeps an open file handler for each used collection (and its indexes). A large number of open file handlers can cause extremely long [checkpoints](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/core/wiredtiger/#snapshots-and-checkpoints) operations.

Furthermore, each of the handles will take about ~22KB memory outside the WT cache; this means that just for keeping the files open, **mongod** process will need ~**NUM_OF_FILE_HANDLES** * 22KB of RAM.

High memory swapping will lead to a decrease in performance.

As you probably understand from the above, different hardware (RAM size & Disk speed) will behave differently.

From my point of view, you first need to understand the behavior of your application then calculate the required hardware for your MongoDB database server.